# shortcut to jump directly to terminal if asked for input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, terminal

I am new with python and VS Code and I wanted to ask if there is a shortcut with which you can jump directly to the terminal when you are asked for an input. I find it annoying that I have to go to the terminal with my mouse every time when asked for an input. It would be perfect if I could just type as soon as I run the program.

I started with coding in the python playground at programiz.pro and there would pop up a input window where you could directly type in your input without moving your cursor.

I'm new to VS Code so I searched for a solution on the internet but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem has an answer already on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1343695). This seems to be something that you can configure in your settings. It may be possible (either natively or through an extension) to configure one hotkey to have two effects, i.e. to first run the program, and then move the cursor to the terminal window.

The relevant portion of the Super User answer is copied below, using the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to move the cursor to the terminal, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to move the cursor (back) to the editor when you're done:

---

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
  "when": "!terminalFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+k",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

> **Step to configure:**

1. Go to: File > Preferences > keyboard shortcuts
2. Then in the search-bar, search for `focus terminal`
3. Select `workbench.action.terminal.focus` and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> or press your custom key and then press enter.
4. Similarly, in the search-bar search for `focus active  editor group`
5. Select  `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup` and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or press your custom key and then press enter.

> **After the above setup:**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to ***focus cursor*** on **terminal**
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to ***focus cursor*** on **coding section** without closing terminal

Comment: what is wrong with `Ctrl+1` and `Ctrl+backtick`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a shortcut for that either but you may open a terminal in a new window so that you can just switch between the windows with `alt+tab`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could set it in keyboard shortcuts(**Ctrl+K Ctrl+S**).

Search for `Terminal: Focus on Terminal View`. Then set a shortcuts for this function. For example, I used `Ctrl+L Ctrl+M`.

[image]

Now, you could use shortcuts to jump to the terminal command line.